# google cloud messaging for chrome api terms of service

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-messaging, google-chrome-app

When I tried to turn on gcm for chrome service in my google APIs console, I see this in terms & conditions,

> Google Cloud Messaging for Chrome API Terms of Service Last modified:
>   September 1, 2012 By using this API, you consent to be bound by these
>   terms in addition to the Google APIs Terms of Service ("API ToS") at
>   http://developers.google.com/terms. API Clients
>
> You and any API Client you create may only access the getChannelId
>   functionality of this API for your own development and personal uses.

The second paragraph is a bit confusing. It sort of says, we cannot use this for commercial applications. Could somebody clarify this information?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer and this should not be construed as legal advice.

Under normal conditions, your API Client (i.e. your server side code that is invoking the GCM APIs) will never need to call the getChannelId API; it will only call the insert method to send a message.  You obtain the channel ID via distinct Javascript APIs that run in the context of your packaged app/extension.

The exception to this is if you create your own build of Chromium, in which case you may need to invoke a number of Google APIs in order for your Chromium build to be fully functional.  This is described here: http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys.  getChannelId has the same terms of service as other APIs used by Chromium that are listed there.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for legal advice, which Stack Overflow answers aren't well-suited to give. This answer isn't legal advice.

Try reading that paragraph from the perspective of Google, who doesn't want developers to **share** client IDs with other developers. Then it might make more sense. One of the purposes of client IDs is to be able to identify and disable requests from specific buggy apps that are hurting the server, without having to shut off everyone's access. Another is to make sure that everyone who uses the API has agreed to the terms of service. If you share your ID with someone else, then two different apps will appear to be the same app, and Google can't be sure that every developer has agreed to the terms of service.

Comment: Sorry, I disagree. The paragraph I pasted in the question does not talk about or imply sharing client IDs. The TOS seem to restrict the usage for personal/development purposes only. The only reason I could see is they want to make make the API service a paid only when used for commerical purpose.